# Why do most languages, still prevalent in 2021, greet with morphemes related to health or peace?

Tags: comparative-linguistics

1. Why do most prevailing prominent Asian, [Middle Eastern](https://www.uri.org/uri-story/20101026-cultural-greeting-peace) and [European](https://aleteia.org/2019/04/28/where-does-the-expression-peace-be-with-you-come-from/)  languages greet with morphemes anent health or peace? I know that "salutation" itself meant "health"  — please see below.
2. Which prominent languages are exceptions, if any? What explains these exceptions? Why don't these mainstream languages don't greet with morphemes anent health or peace?  Surely their speakers must still care about health and peace! Or do they truly disregard well-being?

> #### salute [14]

> *Salute* goes back ultimately to the
> Latin noun *salūs*, a relative of *salvus* ‘safe,
> healthy’ (source of English safe and save). This
> had two main strands of meaning. The primary
> one was ‘health, well-being’, and in that sense it
> lies behind English *salubrious* [16] and *salutary*
> [15]. But by extension it also denoted a ‘wish for
> someone’s well-being’, hence a ‘greeting’, and it
> is this that has given English, via its derived verb
> *salūtāre* ‘greet’, *salute*.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 434 Right column.

Comment: Spanish also uses _a despecho de_ and Portuguese _a despeito de_. Also, what exactly is it you’re not sure of here? _Dépit_ and its cognates mean ‘resentment, anger, disappointment’ and _pesar_ means ‘regret, grief, chagrin’; their meanings aren’t exactly miles apart. So ‘despite’ is either ‘in anger of’ or ‘in grief of’ – both seem about equally logical to me. (This would also be a better fit on [spanish.se] than here, I think, even though it includes Portuguese.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I didn't know that "*pesar* means ‘regret, grief, chagrin’". But these nouns don't mean the same as *spite*! I don't understand how "in grief of" means "in anger of". They aren't equally logical to me.

Comment: You shouldn’t completely change the content of a question like this; you should ask a new question instead (however, now that someone has actually given an answer to the new question, don’t change it back, ’cause that would invalidate the answer). Also, there are plenty of greetings in European languages, even English, that have nothing to do with health: basic informal greetings like _hi_, _hey_ or _hello_ are completely devoid of any meaning (even etymologically) other than that of being a greeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many greetings  do not contain any health or peace. However, it is not clear to me what you are asking. Which languages do not have any greatings that contain an explicit mention of human health? Or languages that do no have any such greeting? (there will likely always be one, even if not commonly used)

Or does just wishing having a good time count for you? When you wish wish good morning, good day (Guten Tag...), good afternoon, good evening, you do not exlicitly mention the kind of welbeing. It is just that the time will be good in general.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to clarify. Better now? does my edit affect your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Many modern Indo-Aryan languages use one of three forms of greeting:

1. नमस्कार (namaskāra),
2. नमस्ते (namaste), both from Sanskrit नमस् (namas) meaning obeisance,
3. राम-राम (rāma-rāma) from the name of the deity राम (rāma)